# Branches on Github not able to reach parity no matter what merges are done

Tags: git, github

I have two branches on Github, a main branch and a staging branch.

Staging is currently one commit ahead of main.

I create a PR, set the base branch to main, and see that it is going to add one commit to main. I hit merge.

Now, when I check main, I see that main is one commit ahead of staging. It seems like the merge added *two* commits instead of just one.

This happens regardless of whether I use merge or rebase & merge. Is there a way to actually bring these two branches to parity on Github itself? I know I could force push to main, or use the CLI, but the main branch is heavily branch protected so I would like to avoid disabling those protections.

Comment: How do you check main?

Answer (score 1):

The merge is also a commit and the merge only happens on `main`. To make the two branches identical, delete the staging branch after the merge and recreate it from `main`.

Comment: How do I avoid this happening again? Seems sorta unclear what went wrong in the first place

Comment: This is how git works, so I do not see anything you want to avoid. When you merge branch `A` to branch `B` then nothing happens to branch `A` but branch `B` has a new commit where the edits from `A` are added to `B`. So a merge is not commutative, meaning that merging `A` into `B` is not the same as merging `B` into `A`. If you want the two branches to be identical after the merge, either delete the "compare" branch after the merge and recreate it from the "base" branch or rebase the "compare" branch onto the "base" branch after the merge.

Comment: Hmm this seems odd to me. In a terminal I can merge branches without creating an extra commit -- these are 'fast forward' merges. Are you saying its not possible to such a merge on Github?

Comment: It is possible to do a fast forward merge on GitHub. But going through a PR tells GitHub not to. You would have to do the merge locally and push the resulting `main` (and your GitHub configuration may forbid that, as I think you've said).

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to avoid this situation under a normal workflow involving PRs (pull requests).

Keep in mind that PRs are *not a Git feature*. Git does not support them in any way. What Git wants is that every push should be a fast-forward on the remote server. Git thinks that pushing should *never* make a merge commit on the server.

PRs totally subvert that. They *do* make a merge commit on the server (which Git thinks should be impossible). That is exactly what you are saying to do, when you "hit merge"! Well, that merge commit is a new commit, so the branch on the server will *necessarily* be ahead of the local after a PR finishes and the branch is merged.

Rebasing won't change that. In fact it would probably add *multiple* commits, putting your local even *further* behind.

Comment: I don't think the "on the server" distinction is real here. Pushing does what pushing always does. Hitting the merge button just creates a merge and pushes it. It's just that the git client doing that is "somewhere else" in GitHub-land instead of on a committer's machine.

Comment: @hobbs No, it's done directly in the server copy of the repository.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. The documentation from Github states: 

`The pull request is merged using the --no-ff option.` 
for default merge PRs.

And: `Pull requests with rebased commits are merged using the fast-forward option.` for rebase-and-merge PRs.

Source:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges

Comment: @theahura I don't see how any of that makes what I said "incorrect". On the contrary.

Comment: The documentation seems to clearly state that you can merge with fast forward using a PR (using rebase-and-merge). You're saying that the very act of using a PR makes this impossible. I'm having trouble getting rebase-and-merge to fast forward, but unless the Github documentation is wrong it seems this should be possible.

Comment: Read more carefully? There is a fast-forward option on rebase, but that is still a rebase, not a fast-forward merge.